# java.security.InvalidKeyException: PBES2 AlgorithmParameters not available

Tags: java, security, ssl

Trying to do a TLS handshake between a client and server. However it is failing the change cipher specification step. Also on the client end am receiving a exception as outlined below: I am not able to understand why I am receiving a weird exception like the below.

What does it mean? Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

I am running it under Java 7.

> java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: PBES2 AlgorithmParameters not
>   available     at
>   sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:159)    at
>   java.security.Security.getImpl(Security.java:695)     at
>   java.security.AlgorithmParameters.getInstance(AlgorithmParameters.java:146)
>     at com.certicom.security.pkcs.pkcs5.g.(Unknown Source)    at
>   com.certicom.security.pkcs.pkcs5.i.a(Unknown Source)  at
>   com.certicom.security.sslplus.b.a(Unknown Source)     at
>   com.certicom.security.cert.internal.x509.PKCS8.decrypt(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   com.certicom.security.cert.internal.x509.SSLPlusSupport.getLocalIdentity(Unknown
>   Source)   at com.certicom.tls.cert.CertLoader.loadLocalIdentity(Unknown
>   Source)   at com.certicom.tls.interfaceimpl.i.a(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.certicom.tls.TLSContext.loadLocalIdentity(Unknown Source)     at
>   com.onstar.emxp.util.TLSClient.loadCert(TLSClient.java:66)    at
>   com.onstar.adc.pd.connection.TLSContextLoader.getTLSContext(TLSContextLoader.java:27)
>     at com.onstar.adc.pd.PacketClient.run(PacketClient.java:74)
>
> java.security.InvalidKeyException: PBES2 AlgorithmParameters not
>   available     at com.certicom.security.pkcs.pkcs5.g.(Unknown
>   Source)   at com.certicom.security.pkcs.pkcs5.i.a(Unknown Source)     at
>   com.certicom.security.sslplus.b.a(Unknown Source)     at
>   com.certicom.security.cert.internal.x509.PKCS8.decrypt(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   com.certicom.security.cert.internal.x509.SSLPlusSupport.getLocalIdentity(Unknown
>   Source)   at com.certicom.tls.cert.CertLoader.loadLocalIdentity(Unknown
>   Source)   at com.certicom.tls.interfaceimpl.i.a(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.certicom.tls.TLSContext.loadLocalIdentity(Unknown Source)     at
>   com.onstar.emxp.util.TLSClient.loadCert(TLSClient.java:66)    at
>   com.onstar.adc.pd.connection.TLSContextLoader.getTLSContext(TLSContextLoader.java:27)
>     at com.onstar.adc.pd.PacketClient.run(PacketClient.java:74)
>
> java.security.KeyManagementException  at
>   com.certicom.security.cert.internal.x509.SSLPlusSupport.getLocalIdentity(Unknown
>   Source)   at com.certicom.tls.cert.CertLoader.loadLocalIdentity(Unknown
>   Source)   at com.certicom.tls.interfaceimpl.i.a(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.certicom.tls.TLSContext.loadLocalIdentity(Unknown Source)     at
>   com.onstar.emxp.util.TLSClient.loadCert(TLSClient.java:66)    at
>   com.onstar.adc.pd.connection.TLSContextLoader.getTLSContext(TLSContextLoader.java:27)
>     at com.onstar.adc.pd.PacketClient.run(PacketClient.java:74) WARNING:
>   Could not load certificate packetserver
>   java.security.KeyManagementException

Client code doing the tls handshake :

> ```
>     socket = new Socket(host, port);
>     InputSSLIOStream inputStream = new InputSSLIOStream(
>     socket.getInputStream());
>     OutputSSLIOStream outputStream = new OutputSSLIOStream(
>     socket.getOutputStream());
>     TLSConnection tlsConnection = tlsContextLoader.getTLSContext()
>                     .getClientConnection(inputStream, outputStream, "server");
>     tlsConnection.startHandshake();
>     socket.setSoTimeout(30000);
>     OutputStream tlsOutputStream = tlsConnection.getOutputStream();
>     InputStream tlsInputStream = tlsConnection.getInputStream();
> ```

My TLS Context loader :

```
public class TLSContextLoader
{
    public TLSContext getTLSContext()
            throws Exception
    {
        TLSContext localTLSContext = new TLSContext();
        localTLSContext.setIsStrongCipherSuiteLimited(false);
        localTLSContext.setHelloProtocol("TLS1-ONLY");
        localTLSContext.setEllipticCurves(new String[] { "secp256r1" });
        localTLSContext.setClientAuthModes(new String[] { "ECDSA_SIGN" });
        localTLSContext.setDebugFlag();
        localTLSContext.setEccDraftCompatibility(-1);
        localTLSContext.setX509BasicConstraintBug(true);
        TLSClient.loadCert(localTLSContext, "packetserver");
        localTLSContext.setPSKParam(new byte[] { 49 });
        localTLSContext.loadTrustedCertificates(KeyLoader.getTrustedStream("rootca"));

        localTLSContext.setRNG(new SecureRandom(generateSeed()));
        LocalTrustManager localLocalTrustManager = new LocalTrustManager();
        localTLSContext.setTrustManager(localLocalTrustManager);
        localTLSContext.setEnabledCipherSuites(EMXPArrays.csvToArray("TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"));

        localTLSContext.setNeedClientAuth(false);
        return localTLSContext;
    }

    private byte[] generateSeed() {
        String str = new String();
        str = str + "IDH" + System.identityHashCode(str);
        Runtime localRuntime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        str = str + "FM" + localRuntime.freeMemory();
        str = str + "CT" + System.currentTimeMillis();
        Properties localProperties = System.getProperties();
        Enumeration localEnumeration = localProperties.elements();
        while (localEnumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
            str = str + localEnumeration.nextElement();
        }
        str = str + "VHC" + str.hashCode();
        return str.getBytes();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above problem was solved . Was using certicom libraries on the client side for security and on the server side was using JDK 7 . When both the client and the server were based on JDK 7 security libraries the client was able to talk to the server and negotiate a handshake .